# How to input data to column based on condition from other column although that column isn't full (Python/CSV)

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have some EEG data but the events that occur only happen every few hundred rows and these events are not numbers.
Thus, I need to create some code that will create a new column that registers these events as an integer (1:8).
BUT! Only the exact onset of the event is marked in the csv. So the remaining cells in the column are blank until another event occurs. So I need the code to repeat the integer given until it sees a new event.
attached is a sample picture of my csv in excel but the spacing is far larger and the data goes on for a VERY long time.

I tried looking online but all the tutorials only give examples when there is information in the matching column the entire time. So I need some if/else statement to make it write the until finding new information in the matching column.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Hvj.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data of csv. You can use `print(df.to_dict("list"))`